# replaceAll function not working while removing special character

Tags: android, json, string, replace

I am working with a project where some data are retrieved by JSON parsing. Unfortunately, invalid character '\' escapes. I need to remove them. I tried calling `.replace("\\'","\");`. This solution is not working. No exceptions are thrown, but the string does not change. Here is my code:

```
shop_name = c.getString(TAG_SHOP_NAME);
if(shop_name.contains("\\'")==true)
{
//try{
shop_name=shop_name.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\'"), "'");
Log.e("vvvvvv","new shop name: "+shop_name);}
//catch(Exception q){Log.e(TAG+" vvvv","EXPTN",q);}
}

send JSON object is: Bimal\'s

required object: Bimal's
```

Please let me know whether I went wrong somewhere or if there is any other method other than replaceAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslash as it's an escape character in both strings and regex:

```
shop_name.replaceAll("\\\\'", "'");
```

Or without using regex (as it's not needed in this circumstance):

```
shop_name.replace("\\'", "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the meta character " with "\" :

string.replaceAll("\"", "");
Remember to assign it back to the String reference , because it returns a new String object.

You should use replace() instead:

str = str.replace("\"", "");
replaceAll() is used for replacing regular expressions.

Comment: thanks for that information. but it still not works with \'. anyway my query is cleared.